# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new in `Linq` and so I have these situation below.

Now below error during compilation, says `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'.`

```
var query = _db.Products;
if (bool) {
  query = query.Where(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

And so I tried to change `var` to `IQueryable` and it works.

```
IQueryable<Product> query = _db.Products;
if (bool) {
  query = query.Where(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

But then, I tried to change it again (see below) and it works.

```
var query = from product in products
            select product;
if (bool) {
  query = query.Where(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

And I just want to know why the other one works, but the other's not.

A good explanation with example might help. Thanks

Comment: Even I have that namespace, still error. But my code above works. Just want to know why.

Comment: Just had the same issue and solved it via the equivalent of `var query = db.Products.Select(x => x);` Yes, it does seem strange to me, too.

Comment: For me `query.AsQueryable().Where(......)` worked

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The reason why the first scenario does not work is that the `System.Linq.IQueryable` is an interface which is implemented, among others, by the `System.Data.Entity.DbSet` class. In C#, if class `C` implements interface `I`, when it comes to transitions between types, you may as well treat `I` as `C`'s base class (even the semantics `class C : I` suggest such an approach). And since you cannot implicitly (i.e. not verbosely) cast a class (or interface) to one of it's descendant classes, you get a compile-time error when trying to do it. You can do the opposite, that is implicitly cast a descendant class to it's base class (or interface). That's exactly what happens in the second scenario.

In your case, you could trick the compiler by casting explicitly:

```
query = (DbSet<Customer>) query.Where(p => p.Id == id);
```

but I would **strongly** advise you not to since you'll end up with a messy exception, because the result of `query.Where(p => p.Id == id)` is not in fact an instance of `DbSet<Customer>`, but rather some class representing the result of a query performed on a `DbSet<Customer>`, which implements the `IQueryable` interface.

So, to sum up, let's go through all the scenarios:

Scenario 1:

```
//query is of type DbSet<Customer>
var query = _db.Products; 
if (bool) {
  //here you're trying to assign a value of type IQueryable<Customer>
  //to a variable of it's descendant type DbSet<Customer>
  //hence the compile-time error
  query = query.Where(p => p.Id == id); 
}
```

Scenario 2:

```
//here you implicitly cast value of type DbSet<Customer>
//to IQueryable<Customer>, which is OK
IQueryable<Customer> query = _db.Products; 
if (bool) {
  //here you're assigning a value of type IQueryable<Customer>
  //to a variable of the same type, which is also OK
  query = query.Where(p => p.Id == id); 
}
```

Scenario 3:

```
//I assume you have the following line in your code
var products = _db.Products;
//query is of type IQueryable<Customer>, because you perform
//a query on the DbSet<Product>
var query = from product in products
            select product;
if (bool) {
  //here you're assigning a value of type IQueryable<Customer>
  //to a variable of the same type, which is OK
  query = query.Where(p => p.Id == id); 
}
```

**EDIT**

It's been a while since I answered this question, and even though the merit of it still stands, I tend to use a slightly different approach (which might have not been available at the time of original answer, I'm not sure).

The simplest (and I believe safest) way of casting an object implementing `IQueryable<T>` to `IQueryable<T>` is this:

```
var query = _db.Products.AsQueryable();
```

This simply returns the subject of the call to its `IQueryable<T>` interface implementation. It should not produce any overhead when executing the query. Now, there are comments suggesting to use some tricks, using which I believe might be a bad idea.

One example of such trick is to use this:

```
var queryable = query.Select(x => x);
```

While being (almost) completely benign when querying objects, it can do some harm when dealing with some implementations of `IQueryable<T>`. Namely, when the query is translated to, for example, a SQL query, it most likely will add a redundant `"SELECT * FROM ..."` to the executed query. That's the best case scenario - in the most probable scenario it will add something greatly more tedious - something like `"SELECT x.P1, x.P2, ... FROM ... AS x"`. Of course, you might be OK with it, but you should be aware of it. Aware of the fact that, depending on implementation, calls like that might not be "free", even though appearing to do nothing.

Another example:

```
query.Where(x => true)
```

will potentially add a `WHERE 1=1` to your SQL query.

Comment: IQueryable<MediaRef> medRef = context.MediaRefs;
if(MediaId!=null)
                medRef=medRef.Where(w=>w.MediaId==MediaId);..but this is not working in my scenario..(Scenario 2)

Comment: @Sadaquat What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Does the code not compile and if so what's the error message? Otherwise, does an exception get thrown and if so what's the exception message?

Comment: its giving compile time error ,same error ..
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<>' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<>, although I have done my work using your scenario 3 approach , but i am curious to know why the scenario 2 gives compile error

Answer (score 10):

When using `var` the compiler infers the type of the expression to the right of the assignment. When you write

```
var query = _db.Products;
```

`query` is of type `DbSet<Product>`, and it cannot be assigned any `IQueryable<Product>`, which the `Where` extension method returns.

When you used the query syntax, `query` was again `IQueryable<Product>`, which made it work. It's equivalent to writing

```
var query = products.Select(t => t);
```

The `Select` extension method, like `Where`, returns `IQueryable<Product>`.

Comment: `products.Select(t => t)` is cool trick, saved me a lot of typing.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `_db.Products` isn't a query, it is a DbSet.

The second block works because you are casting it to IQueryable, and the last one works because it is an actual query.

Comment: So if I declare a `DbSet` and assign it to a generic. The `DbSet` gets cast?

Comment: There are very few reasons to be using `DbSet`, especially in this context. Just query the database.

Comment: DbSet<TEntity> implements IQueryable<TEntity> so it is a query. The problem is not with the 'query.Where(...)', but with the assignment "query = query.Where(...)". In other words the problem is not with the DbSet which is not a Query, but with the Query which is not a DbSet

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = _db.Products.Where(x => true);
if (bool) {
  query = query.Where(p => p.Id == id);
}
```