# Dynamic query building with entity framework core - Build a query "by steps"

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, dbset

I'm trying to make a class to perform a dynamic filters, depending on what parameters I'll send to its "filter" method but I'm facing some difficulties on building my query.

It's more easy to explain with my following code, where I'm simply trying to apply some filters basing on what i receive in input:

```
public class PeopleManager : Controller
    {
        private readonly MyPeopleContext _context;
        public PeopleManager(PeopleContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Person> filter (int? id, string name, int? age)
        {
            var peoplequery = _context.People;
            if(id!=null)
            {
               peoplequery = peoplequery .Where(p => p.Id.Equals(id));
            }

            if(name!="")
            {
               peoplequery = peoplequery .Where(p => p.Name.Contains(name));
            }

            if(age!=null)
            {
               peoplequery  = peoplequery .Where(p => p.Age.Equals(age));
            }

            return peoplequery;
        }
    }
```

Obviously, my code is not working and according to this question that I've found:

[Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969154/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-linq-iqueryable-to-system-data-entity-d)

I've managed to edit my code as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> filter (int? id, string name, int? age)
            {
                var people = _context.People;

                var peoplequery = from p in people select people;

                if(id!=null)
                {
                   peoplequery = peoplequery .Where(p => p.Id.Equals(id));
                }

                if(name!="")
                {
                   peoplequery = peoplequery .Where(p => p.Name.Contains(name));
                }

                if(age!=null)
                {
                   peoplequery  = peoplequery .Where(p => p.Age.Equals(age));
                }

                return peoplequery;
            }
```

But doing this, I can't access to people's properties like id, name, etc... in my lambda expressions.

How can I build this conditional query without any error?

Comment: Remove `var` inside `if` blocks. Currently it won't even compile. Also at the beginning use simply `var peoplequery = _context.People.AsQueryable();`

Comment: @IvanStoev done, it was a copy-paste error while writing the question. I update the question content right now

Comment: Then apply `AsQueryable()` and you are done :) I mean, instead of `from p in ...`.

Comment: @IvanStoev So it will figure out as: `var people= _context.People.AsQueryable();`, without declaring the `var peoplequery = from p in people select people;` right?

Comment: Right. Same as `IQueryable<Person> people = _context.People;` Or `var people = from p in _context.People select p;` (note `select p`, not `people`). But `AsQueryable()` is the shorter.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks! Now it works fine! Just a quick question that for a beginner like me could be useful... In your advice, are there any risks on returning an IQueryable on this filter method, that actually expects to return an IEnumerable?

Comment: If you look at the declaration of the interfaces, you will see that `IQueryable<T>` inherits `IEnumerable<T>`, so no problem (from OOP, queryablle *is a* enumerable)

Comment: changing `var peoplequery = _context.People;` to `IQueryable<Person>  peoplequery = _context.People;` should sort this

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want to have smth like this:

```
public class PeopleController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyPeopleContext _context;

    public PeopleManager(PeopleContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Person> Filter (int? id, string name, int? age)
    {
        var peoplequery = _context.People.AsQueryable();
        if(id.HasValue)
        {
           peoplequery = peoplequery.Where(p => p.Id == id.Value);
        }
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
           peoplequery = peoplequery.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(name));
        }
        if(age.HasValue)
        {
           peoplequery = peoplequery.Where(p => p.Age == age.Value);
        }

        return peoplequery.ToArray();
    }
}
```